# How to get subject dn with python

Tags: python, ssl, python-sockets

What would be a nice way to get SSL's Subject DN with python ?

This includes things like:

- Country name
- State name
- Locality name
- Org name
- Common name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```py
import ssl
import socket
from pprint import pprint


hostname = 'www.example.com'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        pprint(ssock.getpeercert()['subject'])
```

Outputs:

```py
((('countryName', 'US'),),
 (('stateOrProvinceName', 'California'),),
 (('localityName', 'Los Angeles'),),
 (('organizationName', 'Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers'),),
 (('commonName', 'www.example.org'),))
```

Read more about `getpeercert()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLSocket.getpeercert